# didReceiveLocalNotification, didReceiveRemoteNotification and willPresentNotification never triggered when notifications show up, React Native App

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement notifications in a react-native app, on iOS, and I'm facing a strange issue. The app is able to show local notifications, and to show remote notifications coming from firebase, but it does not trigger the event "onNotification" of react-native-push-notification as expected. I have been through many forums looking for a solution but I still haven't found one yet, that's why I request your help.

After investigating, i realized that the objective-c functions "didReceiveLocalNotification" and "didReceiveRemoteNotification" are never triggered, so i supposed it is the reason why "onNotification" does not trigger either. Unfortunately I'm a total beginner in this language so I can't understand the cause of the problem.

Looking at the "didReceiveLocalNotification" documentation, I read that this function is deprecated, and that I should use "willPresentNotification" instead, but like the others it's never triggered.

For the record, I've followed this guide to handle notification in iOS : 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client. I'm testing on iOS 13, react-native 0.60.5, push-notifiaction-ios ^1.0.2, react-native-push-notification ^3.1.3 and react-native-firebase ^5.5.6.

AppDelegate.m

```c
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  if ([FIRApp defaultApp] == nil) {
    [FIRApp configure];
    [FIRMessaging messaging].delegate = self;
  }
  if ([UNUserNotificationCenter class] != nil) {
    // iOS 10 or later
    // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
    [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
    UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptionAlert |
        UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
    [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]
        requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions
        completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
          // ...
        }];
  } else {
    // iOS 10 notifications aren't available; fall back to iOS 8-9 notifications.
    UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
    (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
    [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
  }

  [application registerForRemoteNotifications];

  // Load RootView ...

  return YES;
}
// sourceURLForBridge function ...

// Required to register for notifications
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
}
// Required for the register event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}
// Required for the notification event. You must call the completion handler after handling the remote notification.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
  // Never called
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}
// Required for the registrationError event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];
}
// Required for the localNotification event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
  // Never called
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
}

//Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler
{
  // Never called
  completionHandler(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge);
  //completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);
}
```

PushNotification and firebase configuration

```js
function configurePushNotification(){
  PushNotification.configure({
    onRegister: function(token) {
      console.warn("TOKEN:", token);
    },
    onNotification: function(notification) {
      console.warn("NOTIFICATION:", notification);

      // Never called

      notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
    },
    permissions: {
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true
    },
    popInitialNotification: true,
    requestPermissions: true
  });
}
async function checkPermission(onReady) {
  const enabled = await firebase.messaging().hasPermission();
  if (enabled) {
    console.warn('checkPermission enabled');
    getToken(onReady);
  } else {
    console.warn('checkPermission disabled');
    requestPermission(onReady);
  }
}

async function requestPermission(onReady) {
  try {
    await firebase.messaging().requestPermission();
        // User has authorised
        console.warn('requestPermission try');
        getToken(onReady);
  } catch (error) {
        // User has rejected permissions
        console.error(error)
        console.warn('requestPermission rejected');
    }
}

async function getToken(onReady) {
  fcmToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('fcmToken');
  if (!fcmToken) {
    fcmToken = await firebase.messaging().getToken();
    if (fcmToken) {
          // user has a device token
          await AsyncStorage.setItem('fcmToken', fcmToken);
      }
  }
  console.warn(fcmToken)
  if(onReady) onReady()
}

class App extends React.Component {

  async componentDidMount() {
    checkPermission()
    configurePushNotification()
  }

  render(){
    return (
      // View ...
    )
  }
};
```

Thank you for your help !

**EDIT**: After investigating, I realized that these events stop working after i added Firebase/Messaging to my podfile. But according to the firebase documentation, it is not the normal behaviour. Any Idea about the reason of this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've a way to do it.

I didn't exactly figure out why the events are not called in AppDelegate.m, but i've noticed that the same events implemented by Firebase Messaging (went to the code in Pods/Development Pods/RNFirebase/messaging and notifications) are called when notification shows up. So I assume that this code override mine in AppDelegate.m.

In fact i wasn't listening the good Javascript events. The events specified here https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/messaging/receiving-messages and here https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/receiving-notifications work for me in iOS. But these events are not called on android...

So I ended handling notifications differently on Android and on iOS, using:

- "onNotification" of react-native-push-notification for Android
- "onNotification" and "onNotificationOpened" of react-native-firebase for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Local notifications are sent by device.

Remote notifications (APNS) are sent by your server, delivered by Apple server.
You send a notification to Apple, who send a notification to device, if allowed.

If you are using a service like Firebase, you send notification to Firebase, Firebase send notification to Apple, Apple send notification to user.

Firebase Cloud Messaging use method swizzling in ObjC, [as explained in documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client). So, `onNotification` is not called.

I suggest [using this component for React Native](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm). There's a sample app in source code with a configured `AppDelegate.m`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! react-native-fcm seems to be deprecated, anyway I'm going to try the sample app this evening and see if it can help me.